# Android webview download data/text file

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I have developed an android webview and trying to download a generated data:text file upon click on the link in webview.

```
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
```

But, i'm getting the following error exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: data:text/vcard;base64,qadsasffaefqawdfafafasdasdasdasdadasd
```

Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution? I ham having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
            intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Do not forget to give this permission! This is very important! Add this in your Manifest file(The AndroidManifest.xml file)

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried it out with your code, but still getting the same error exception.

Comment: can i get the url you are using in your webview

Comment: when click on the link in webview, it should download the vCard.vcf. The format should be something like

BEGIN:VCARD
N:123123;123;123123;test;
EMAIL;INTERNET:123123123213
END:VCARD

It is just a plain text file, when i click the link in mobile browser, it can download automatically but not in the webview :( 

Is it because of non-http/https url for the file? May I know how to overcome this scenario?

Comment: The uri that i try to open and download is data uri. I think download manager cannot open it and download.

Answer (score -1):

To download, try this:

```
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
if(!url.contains("http://"){
    newurl=("http://"+url);
}
else
{
   newurl=url;
}
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(newurl));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

The method onDownloadStart is used to tell the system what to do once the download has already begun.

Another way is editing your initial code:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
String newurl;
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
    if(!url.contains("http://"){
        newurl=("http://"+url);
    }
    else
    {
       newurl=url;
    }
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(newurl));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }
});
```

Not sure if this will work though

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with your code but getting error exception "ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data:text/vcard;base64,aderertsaweqw"

Comment: Have you added this line to manifest: '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>'

Comment: I cannot say why that's happening.....are you launching the download from an activity or service/asynctask ?

Comment: The uri that i try to open and download is data uri. I think download manager cannot open it and download. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It appears as if the url link doesn't contain the prefix "http://" or "ftp". Try the edited code with the if/else condition.